# cefsharp.browsersubprocess - how to properly kill it

Tags: cefsharp

At work, our app is starting cefsharp.browsersubprocess.
I'm integrating our app with squirrel.windows - the autoupdate framework.

After an update, our app runs a squirrel method which starts up another squirrel process (update.exe), then does environment.exit on our app.  (then, update.exe will wait for our app to exit, then will start the newer version of our app).

What happens is that libcef throws an error to the event manager at the point (4000001f), I guess because we killed its father (our app) but didn't kill cefsharp.browsersubprocess.

If my theory is correct (would love to get a confirmation on that), I plan on modifying squirrel's method by getting a list of child processes of our app, then killing them (it's gonna be only cefsharp.browsersubprocess) before doing environment.exit on our app.

How should I properly kill it? by process.Kill? by process.CloseMainWindow?

Thank!

Comment: What version are you using? The browser subprocess should terminate themselves when the parent process exist by default, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/93/CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core/BrowserSubprocessExecutable.h#L126 which process exactly is generating the error? It doesn't sound like your application is being terminated gracefully which is not ideal, CEF needs to shutdown properly.

Comment: Subprocess are somewhat transient and generally shouldn't care if they are terminated.

Comment: thanks @amaitland, after more investigation I found out that: 1. our app is being terminated by process.kill, 2. I think that the problem is that process.kill (the way we kill our app today and not getting any error from libcef) is more brutal than environment.exit, which "lets" libcef sending an error. so maybe I should terminate the app using process.kill which is ugly but works (=doesn't report to event viewer). anyway, the process generating the error is werfault

Comment: Process.CloseMainWindow will send a WM_CLOSE message to the main window allowing for a graceful exit, that would be preferable assuming your application can exit without prompting the user with a dialog etc. You could combine Process.WaitForExit and then forcefully terminate the process if required. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,3abe28bbc909290d

Answer (score 0):

It works great for me.

```
internal static void AppRestart()
{
    ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Info.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 1 & START \"\" \"" +
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) +
        "\\..\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\"";
    Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    Process.Start(Info);
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```